# What is the use of "cleartool co -nc -unr $m" in shall script?

Tags: bash

I was using a bash script but I didn't get what is the purpose of this line

```
for m in $MAKEFILES; do  
if [ -f $m ]; then  
echo "processing $m ... "</br>  
**cleartool co -nc -unr $m**  
MAKENAME=$(basename $m)  
print_header | sed "s/XXXXXXXXXX/$MAKENAME/g" > $TMPDIR/$MAKENAME  
sed '1,/####################/d' $m >> $TMPDIR/$MAKENAME  
cp $TMPDIR/$MAKENAME $m  
rm -f $TMPDIR/$MAKENAME
#cleartool ci -c "updated file header" $m << ENDL  

#ENDL  
fi  
done
```

Comment: Have you tried *searching* for what `cleartool` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is performing a clearcase/UCM checkout (unreserved if already reserved) on the file `$m`

```
cleartool co -nc -unr $m
```

The global purpose of the shell seems to be to update file header on a clearcase system:

1. checkout file using `cleartool co` so file becomes writable
2. update the file to add/update header
3. checkin the file to update the version in clearcase system.